# How can I safely restart a Node application which receives a high volume of traffic?

Tags: node.js, pm2

For example, in the Python world you would use uWSGI or Gunicorn to restart your Python web app if stopped running for any reason, e.g. memory leaks, unexpected runtime errors, etc. However this is done in such a way that connections aren't dropped (so no 502s).

Looking at the options for Node it seems PM2 is a popular choice but I have two concerns:

1. Can it make the same guarantees regarding connection draining (no 502s, please)?
2. When I looked at PM2 before it seemed to cause significant performance degradation in my application where every millisecond of latency counts (100s of added ms).

So my question is, where performance is a serious consideration and we can't drop connections while restarting, what are Node's uWSGI and Gunicorn equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some strategies:

1. **Use node.js clustering with N worker processes.**  You can then restart any single worker process and not affect overall availability.
2. **Use a load balancer in front of multiple clusters.**  Then temporarily configure the load balancer to only send traffic to one cluster.  When the deconfigured cluster has finished with all open connnections, you can then restart all the processes in that cluster.
3. **For even more flexibility, use multiple clusters on separate machines.**  That allows you to even take a server machine down for hardware maintenance without disrupting overall availability.

If you have resources among multiple clustered processes such as databases, then you will also need redundancy for them in order to be able to restart them without interruption.

Now of course, you have to make sure that taking some part of your system out of service for reboot or maintenance still leaves you with enough service capacity so you would typically do this when overall service load is low (4am for your largest user base).

PM2 is one such tool that allows you to do portions of what is recommended here (such as clustering and seamlessly restarting part of a cluster).  There are other tools.